# Ignore .babelrc relative to a node_module

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

When `import`'ing `node_modules` modules through Webpack (using `babel-loader`), is there a way to tell it not to look for a `.babelrc` file in that resources folder. Like I don't want to perform certain babel opperations on that file.

So: **Is there a way to ignore `node_modules` `.babelrc` files when using `babel-loader`?**

To illustrate, my folder strucutre:

```
node_modules
    myModule
        index.js
        .babelrc # ignore this file

index.js # require('myModule')
.babelrc # only use this babelrc file
webpack.config.js # entry: index.js with a babel-loader plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the babelrc [Lookup Behavior](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#lookup-behavior):

> Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file
>   being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the
>   directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json
>   with a "babel": {} hash within.
>
> Use "babelrc": false in options to stop lookup behavior, or provide
>   the --no-babelrc CLI flag.

Alternatively, you could add an `.npmignore` file to `myModule`, and then add `.babelrc` to your `.npmignore` file. In this case, your .babelrc file in `node_modules/myModule` does not get published and won't appear in that dir, and therefore Babel will continue to look up the directory tree according to the Lookup Behavior (I've personally tried this approach)

[npm ignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

> Use a .npmignore file to keep stuff out of your package.

Comment: But I don't have control over this module, becuase its a node_module.